# React Native targetSdkVersion 30 but play store shows 28

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

React Native targetSdkVersion is set to 30 but play store shows 28

```js
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    // buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    // ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    fitnessVersion = "20.0.0"
}
```

When I upload .aab file Google play says that my current targetSdkVersion is 28 but in /android/build.gradle it is 30

[image: Google play upload error says that current version is 28]

Comment: can you please share app/build.gradle file? where you might have mentioned this version

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danik0011/ae6780e575d09b6b48bd14abcaf210cb

Here is my app/build.rgadle

Comment: line number 138 should be `targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion` instead of `targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersion`